# How can i do a percentage calculation based on a cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet when column K contains the type of policy using a shortcode.

When this shortcode is NET94 i need this to be changed to NOPL95 and also for the cell in Column AC to be be 95% of the value in column AA.

I have already created a macro which loops to delete cells perfectly and i want to add this into the loop.

The code that i am trying doesn't seem to work and i can't find anything online which fits with this.

```
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row


    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

'Amend Net94 & NET03H to NOPL95
    With .Cells(Lrow, "AC")
    If Not IsError(.Value) Then
    If .Value = "NET94" Or .Value = "NET03H" Then .Value = "NOPL95" And .Cells(Lrow, "AC").Value = .Cells(Lrow, "AA") * 95 / 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [not what `And` is for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251591%28v=office.14%29.aspx). If you want to more than one thing to occur when a given condition is satisfied, then you need to put each of those things on a separate line, and terminate the block with an `End If`, like this:

```
    If .Value = "NET94" Or .Value = "NET03H" Then 
        .Value = "NOPL95" 
        .Cells(Lrow, "AC").Value = .Cells(Lrow, "AA") * 95 / 100
    End If
```

See [documentation for `If...Then...Else`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee440532%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: That does seem right, but when i try to put this into practise it seems to ignore the IF statement and just applies .value = "NOPL95" to all cells

Comment: Have you tried debugging as instructed here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx